# How to apply 2D gravitational effects to sprites

Tags: math, 2d, game-physics

Within a 2D infinite space, I have two circular sprites that represent massive bodies in outer space.

Each body has a pair of `x`, `y` coordinates, a `mass`, a `speed` and a `direction` (in radians).

On each frame of animation, I'm running the following code for each body (where `this` is the body being updated, and `other` is the other body):

```py
x, y = other.x - this.x, other.y - this.y

angle = atan2(y, x)
distance = root(square(x) + square(y))
force = this.mass * other.mass / square(distance)
```

Note: I'm ignoring *G* as it's just a multiplier.

I know how to move the bodies around, based on their coordinates, speed and direction, but do not know how to update `this.speed` and `this.direction` to simulate gravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gravitational force acting on a given body is represented as a vector and produces acceleration with components (`ax` and `ay`), which are calculated (based on what you already have) like this:

```
squared_distance = square(x) + square(y)
distance = sqrt(squared_distance)

accel = other.mass / squared_distance    
ax = accel * x / distance 
ay = accel * y / distance
```

Note that the `angle` (force/acceleration direction) is not needed.

Each body should have an associated velocity (instead of `speed`), which should be a two-component vector (`vx` and `vy`). It is updated like this (where `dt` is the time interval between updates):

```
this.vx += ax * dt
this.vy += ay * dt
```

Once the velocity of a given body has been updated, it can then be repositioned (updating its `x`, `y` coordinates) like this:

```
this.x += this.vx * dt
this.y += this.vy * dt
```

You can calculate the speed and direction if you need them, but they are not needed here.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  velocity = force * time?  The units make no sense.  Where is acceleration in these equations?  Where is F = ma?  The physics are completely wrong.  How could this be acceepted?

Comment: @duffymo: That's not *completely* wrong, if you assume that "force" is just a fancy term for "acceleration". They are directly proportional, with the object's mass being the constant of proportionality.

Comment: @duffymo  You are right, I missed that mass here is not 1, because concentrated on vector approach ;)